# Amplitude inversion circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, audio, synthesizer

I am a beginner in electric circuit building and I am trying to build a specific circuit aimed for audio transformation (guitar efx pedal, euro rack etc). I have built a number of implementations of this specific "dynamic inverter" before in some digital audio applications in the past but now I would like to learn how to build it with analog circuits.

The goal is to change the input of the signal (v/amplitude) so that it "inverts" the value around it's max/min scale offset. It might be easier so explain with a graph or by example:

Imagine that the signal scale is from +5 (Vmax) to -5 (Vmin).
The "forumla" should be something like: Vout = Vmax/Vmin - Vin

- When an input voltage is +5 the output should be: +-0v
- When an input voltage is +4 the output should be: +1v
- When an input voltage is +3 the output should be: +2v
- When an input voltage is +2 the output should be: +3v
- When an input voltage is +1 the output should be: +4v
- When an input voltage is +-0 the output should be: +-5v

Same on the negative phase:

- When an input voltage is -5 the output should be: 0v
- When an input voltage is -4 the output should be: -1v
- When an input voltage is -3 the output should be: -2v
- When an input voltage is -2 the output should be: -3v
- When an input voltage is -1 the output should be: -4v

[image]

The attached image shows two wave forms.

1. sine wave, red (input)
2. the transformed, blue (output)

I have started to play around with Circuit JS1 and think that the solutions can be made with op-amps and with some kind of combination with: phase split, each phase invert process, and then put them back together somehow.

How can this be done?

Comment: I’d suspect the tricky part would be the zero crossover as it depends on direction. Apart from that, should be doable with two opamps and two references. At very low input amplitude, do you expect a near square wave output at full amplitude?

Comment: Thanks for the input @winny!
I have solved the phase split and the almost done with the inversion but I do not know how to "add them back together", or if there is a more clever way to solve this.

Yes close to 0v it will output distorted noise. :) 

There is a bit of a weird though behind this idea and that is the greater input the closer towards silence you get, and vice versa.

I guess some kind of limiter will be needed in the analog world. I have also thought of adding some kind of low pass filters to it.

Comment: At first glance it looks like one inverter, bipolar reference voltages, and an SPDT analog switch.  Two problems are noise around the zero-crossing that must be solved without a Schmitt trigger, and variable offsets caused by variable amplitude.  I can see how to solve this in a DSP, but in all analog circuits this is a very difficult problem.

Comment: @AnalogKid seems right. Since peak detection and zero crossing detection occur at different times, any solution is frequency-dependent. Even DSP solution would be a bit complex. This Q might be appropriate for *Signal Processing Stack Exchange*.

Comment: Thanks @glen_geek and Analogkid. I will spend some more time with my virtual env to see who these things work. I have not really worked with electric circuits since high school (many years ago) and need to be put in the right direction where to start looking.

Comment: @Bdrone - Hi, Unfortunately there's been a problem :( You asked a question (ok), got an answer (ok), then added your own "answer" which was actually a follow-up **question** asking for advice about a proposed solution. That last part is not ok. You wrote (effectively) a question, as an answer. That's not allowed on Stack Exchange, where Q&A are in different places. It is also too late to add that proposed solution into your question, as you already received an answer to the original version, so it would make the existing answer appear incomplete (not ok). Your "answer" has been deleted.

Comment: (cont) So now the only rules-complaint option is to wait for answers to this original question, until you feel *this one* is answered enough. Then consider using the advice [here](/help/someone-answers) on the answer(s) you received on the first question. Then, if needed, ask a new follow-up question (which can include asking about a proposed solution). The new question must be stand-alone & not *rely* on people reading this first question (so include a summary for context), but it should include a link back to here. Make it clear here that *this* question is finished, before asking a new one.

Comment: @Bdrone - FYI, after I posted the above advice, site member *[AnalogKid](/u/157935)* decided to give feedback on the proposed solution you were asking about, by posting it (with the required reference acknowledging the source) as part of an actual [answer](/a/697495). That may avoid you needing to ask a new question to get feedback on it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this ...

[image]

Comment: Thanx! This looks like what I need as a start! I will try to create that circuit in Circuit JS1 and check the output.

Comment: That works only for a fixed-amplitude sine.  For anything else, at the time of the zero-crossing you do not know what the upcoming peak amplitude will be, so how do you set the offset?

Comment: This is way easier in the DSP world when we are bound to -1.000 to 1.000 :) But My plan was to have an offset +/- DC which ican be changed from something in the ball park of 0 to +/- 5 volt. I maybe are thinking this wrong? But there must be some kind of voltage limiter at the end I guess.

Comment: @AnalogKid just sample the peak of the input ...

Comment: Which input peak - the one that was before the current zero-crossing (where the output voltage jumps to the peak) or the one after the current zero-crossing (and how would that work?).  And with a complex musical waveform, how does one peak relate - in a predictable manner - to whatever follows 1 millisecond later?

Comment: @AnalogKid you are right for "dynamic" behavior. Just saying that it is a "distortion" added ... I should use the peak every some 20 to 50 ms ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the waveform drawing in the question.  I'm sure it conveys accurately what the TS wants, but it implies that as the overall amplitude of the input signal changes, the two halves of the output waveform decrease in amplitude with a corresponding shift in the respective DC offsets so the both halves still "touch" the output baseline, 0 V or GND.  If this is in fact what the TS wants, getting the offsets to track the two inverted waveforms' peak values is a real problem for something other than a sine input.  Without the DC offset shifts, the output signal would be a square wave noise burst when the input was 0 V.

***BUT*** there is a different output that maintains the core feature of the question without all of the offset mess - Do the inversion without the offsets.  The drawing in the question is basically the two inverted halves of the input riding on a squarewave that is 1/2 the amplitude of the input.  Get rid of the squarewave.

The TS *[Bdrone](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/361770/bdrone)* posted a proposed schematic that could be very close to a solution.  Here is that schematic, from their [deleted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/697483) (only visible to >10k users).

[image: schematic]

Keep the two precision half-wave rectifiers and inverters (minus the offset connections), but then sum the two waveforms through AC coupling capacitors.  Delete the pre-switcher opamps and the analog switches.  Keep the output opamp as a gain stage and buffer/driver.  It also is an inverting summer for the two ac-coupled signals.  You now have the individual half-cycles inverted, but no DC offsets.  The output waveform would go from -T/2 to +T/2, half the input amplitude, but that is easily corrected in the output stage.

Now that I think about it, this is not a new idea.  I've seen this technique in a voice scrambler back in the 70's - 80's.